# How do I go about unit testing mountebank stub configurations?

Tags: unit-testing, mountebank

My mountebank stub configuration is getting complicated enough that I'd like to have regression tests for it.

I'd like to be able to have unit tests for it. Is there a way to do this without having to spin up mountebank and make REST calls to it?